# Elastic Search - empty array?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to return a 'hit' for finding an empty array, I have the following query:

```
GET /universally_searchable/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*",
          "fields": [
            "name^
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": [],
    "must_not": [
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "extensions.organization.markets"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
```

Where extensions.organization.markets needs to be an empty array, but the array exists on all the results so I get all the organizations where I just wanted the ones that have empty markets arrays..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) And I assume you need to add proper mapping

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "fields": [
              "name^"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "extensions.organization",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "markets"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```